# button text disappeared after resizing of button

Tags: html, button, notepad++, tex

I'm re-editing html code for a client but when i changed the size of the button the text disappeared?

here is the code i'm using in Notepad++....

```
<button ="join for free" align="center" style=" font face: trebuchet ms; color: #262626; width: 20%; height: 25px; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #fffd40 "value="Join for Free!"></button>
```

i used the button without the width and height and it was so small u could almost not see the button, so i added the width and height and now it doesn't show the text 'join for free'

any suggestions?
many thank in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<button  align="center" style=" font face: trebuchet ms; color: #262626; width: 20%; height: 25px; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #fffd40;">join for free</button>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NmV2y/)**